# Авторизация в nginx без пароля, только по логину

Tags: nginx

Случилось так что с нескольких серверов необходимо обращаться к серверу nginx.
Например сервера - `host1`,`host2`,`host3`
Каждый сервер при обращение через курл подставлял бы свое имя `-u host1:` и при этом проходила бы авторизация, если такое имя есть в файле с пользователями. Но на данный момент если не заполнить пароль, то появляется ошибка:

```
crypt_r() failed (22: Invalid argument)
```

Искал в гугле что либо похожее, но везде одно и тоже пишут, как настоить логин-пароль связку.
Может быть кто-то сталкивался или сможет помочь?
Устроит вариант если будет один пароль для всех пользователей, но именно логины нужно брать из файла.

Comment: Так и делайте, создайте сколько вам нужно пользователей с одним паролем и никаких проблем

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, проблема в том что у меня может быть > 20к серверов которые будут обращаться к nginx, придется делать все таки бекэд, судьбу не обмануть.

Comment: без двоеточия слать пользователя надо если нет пароля

Comment: с модулями nginx ответы будут приниматься? `ngx_http_auth_request_module`, `ngx_http_auth_jwt_module` ?

Comment: @МихаилРебров, думаю лишнем не будет в любом случае

Comment: @eri, тогда он просит ввести пароль в консоли и если его оставить пустым, то ошибка возникает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```bash
$ curl -u test1: http://192.168.0.1:2480/
<html><body><h1>It works!</h1>
<p>This is the default web page for this server.</p>
<p>The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.</p>
</body></html>
```

```bash
$ curl -u test2: http://192.168.0.1:2480/
<html>
<head><title>401 Authorization Required</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>401 Authorization Required</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.10.3</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Конфиг Nginx:

```
server {
        listen 2480;
        listen [::]:2480;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                proxy_pass       http://1c83:80;
                proxy_set_header Host      $host:$server_port;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                resolver 127.0.0.1;
                auth_basic "Unauthorized";
                auth_basic_user_file /var/www/passto/.htpasswd;
        }
}
```

Файл с паролем:

```
exampleuser:{PLAIN}examplepassword
test1:{PLAIN}
```

Answer (score 1):

Испольуйте [базовую HTTP авторизацию](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-http-basic-authentication/) на уровне вашего Nginx. В запросе через Curl будете передавать заголовок Authorization.

```
curl -H "Authorization: ....." url
```

Comment: у curl есть ключ `-u` его более удобно использовать для ввода логина и пароля, но мне нужно что бы пароль подходил пустой, видимо сама реализация базовой авторизации не позволяет этого